# Expanse Theme - Update Metafield Variant On Shopify Product

Tags: javascript, json, shopify, liquid

I'm working on Shopify and using Expanse theme right now, and I'm still new sorry, because most of my project is WordPress.

I'm trying to create Metafields Variant with Size, Color.

I already displayed the variants, but the problem, the page need to refresh before it change, is there a way on to fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
<div class="variant__description" data-variant-id="{{variant.id}}" {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id == variant.id %} style="display: block;" {% endif %}>
{% if variant.metafields.custom.variant_size %}
<p><span class="font-body-bold">Dimension:</span>{{ variant.metafields.custom.variant_size }}</p>
{% endif %}
{% if variant.metafields.custom.variant_cubage %}
<p><span class="font-body-bold">Cubage:</span>{{ variant.metafields.custom.variant_cubage }}</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
{%- endfor -%}
```

Change product variants metafields base on product selected size or colors

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Built-in variant preset to do so.

It will give you a built-in search and filter feature as well in the front end.

Please check below screen-shot how you can add size and color variants for the product.

[image: add product variant]

ref: https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/variants/add-variants

If any doubts please comment